# Java extended String split regex for brackets

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split a string by the first appearance of "(" and last ")".

For example I have a string: recordWith( camera(), smartphone() );

I want:

```
        [0] recordWith
        [1] camera()
        [2] smartphone()
```

I had the regex `"[\\()]"` but this splits all brackets.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
^([^()]*)\((.*)\)([^()]*)$
```

Will split the input string into three captures.

Explanation:

The `^` and `$` anchor the match to the whole input string.

The `([^()]*)` part finds zero or more characters that are not round brackets and save them in the first capture group, the outer round brackets denote a capture group.

The `\(` matches the first real bracket.

The `(.*)` captures the middle section.

The `\)` matches the last bracket.

The `([^()]*)` finds zero or more characters that are not round brackets.

Regular expression checked with Notepad++ 6.6.7. Do not have access to Java to say how to make use of the captured values.

Answer (score 1):

Look for preceding and following whitespace.

```
String s = "recordWith( camera(), smartphone() )";
String[] parts = s.split("[(,]\\s+|\\s+\\)$");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output

```
[recordWith, camera(), smartphone()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method and it will in all the case whether there is any space or not after parenthesis and comma.

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR5cQ3/7)

```
String s="recordWith( camera(), smartphone() )";    
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\((?!\\))\\s*|\\s*\\)$|,\\s*")));
```

OR

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR5cQ3/12)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("\\s*(\\((?!\\))|,|(?<!\\()\\))\\s*")));
```

output:

```
[recordWith, camera(), smartphone()]
```